# How to disable "right click acting as left click"

Tags: macos, mouse, click, contextual-menu

I have this problem where I press the right click, and the mouse moves a few nanometer over the contextual-menu. When a release the right click, the system acts as if I just did a left click on the contextual-menu and do the action like "copy" or "change page"... This can lead to pretty annoying consequences.

The solution would be to stop the right click being treated as a left click when the mouse moves over the contextual-menu before the right click is released. I don't know if that's possible but honestly I doubt anybody use that feature in the first place.
Another solution would be to make the contextual menu appear after the right click is released, instead of after the right click is pressed, if that is possible.

Comment: What kind of mouse are you using? Apple's Magic Mouse or something different?

Comment: A very cheap PC mouse!

Comment: Finally, I find someone having the same issue than me. I posted a question on superuser, I thought at first it was a Firefox issue, but it isn't because I can reproduce when using other contexts or applications: https://superuser.com/q/1546708/164524 Note that I can reproduce Note that I can also reproduce with the Magic Mouse but also with a Razer mouse. So it isn't related to the device neither.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behaviour & depends how long you hold your initial click for.

This is the same for any menu item on regular left click too. It is observed through the entire macOS.

1. Short click & the menu will wait for another distinct click.
2. Click & hold & it will trigger as soon as you let go.

If your mouse has a dodgy button, it may let go before you *think* you did, causing behaviour 2.

With behaviour 1, you can just take your time wandering around sub menus without having to click anything until you're completely ready. The menu will just wait for you.

As some appear to misinterpret this, here are two examples. The circle round the cursor is the click indicator, green is right, black is left…

**short click** - you can wander around the menu as you wish, even leave its bounds & return, it won't trigger until you click a second time, or click outside it to dismiss.

[image]

**long click/click & hold** - this will trigger as soon as you let go of the mouse button

[image]

Comment: It isn't a solution. The "bug" occurs because we "forget" about this "feature". In fact, we want to disable it, not modifying a behaviour.

Comment: Not knowing how to use it does not make it "a bug". This has been standard Mac toolbox behaviour since 10.0

Comment: Hi. Is it documented somewhere? That's what I wanted to know if it was a bug or a feature. So, nothing to modify this?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea if it's documented, or if it's changeable. It's just been that way for so long it's simply "how it works".

Comment: OK, I understand. :) That's a pity we can't change things like this.

Comment: Saying you're clicking too long is a disrespectful and stupid answer. It will also happen when you click for a normal amount of time (the human definition of releasing instantly) if the mouse moves at all in that time, things can happen. I end up going back pretty frequently in chrome because of this bad behavior, just because the mouse moves a tiny amount in between the time mouse down and mouse up occurs. I would downvote this if I had the repuation.

Comment: @S.Buda -  It's not 'disrespectful' in the slightest. It's how the operating system works. It has two modes of behaviour, depending entirely on the length of time you hold your first click. How on earth can that be 'disrespectful'???

Comment: I've added gifs of each behaviour type.

Comment: The thing those gifs miss is that it happens practically instantly. So if I click and release and my mouse moved at the same time, it can tigger that behavior unexpectedly. I shouldn't be poised with my mouse trying to release right click with a perfectly steady hand as fast as I can. I'm trying to work, not play a game with precision inputs.

Comment: In the comments where you say "Not knowing how to use it does not make it a bug" is what rubs me the wrong way. I understand the behavior, but it triggers "accidentally" depending on how I click. Your comment read to me as typical apple user elitism, and I am maybe too sensitive to that, but it feels dismissive of the actual issue to me.